# Can't connect to existing collection in MongoDB via node.js API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have already created a collection with a large amount of documents in MongoDB. Now, I am writing an API to connect to this, using this tutorial: https://www.bezkoder.com/node-express-mongodb-crud-rest-api/

After using MongoDB Compass I realised that there was another collection created. I changed any mention of "repositories" to "repository" in node.js and re-ran the API. Unfortunately, the same problem occurred.

I'm guessing that mongoose automatically creates a collection "repositories"
(Yes the name should probably be changed to something more suitable).

So, how can I connect to the existing "repository" collection?

To confirm there's no issue with connecting to the database:

> ```
> `For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
>  Debugger attached.
>  Server is running on port 8080.
>  Connected to the database!
> ```

Here is the schema (according to my existing collection):

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
    var schema =
      mongoose.Schema(
        {
          cord_uid: String,
          sha: String,
          source_x: String,
          title: String,
          doi: String,
          pmcid: String,
          license: String,
          abstract: String,
          publish_time: String,
          authors: String,
          journal: String,
          pdf_json_files: String,
          pmc_json_files: String,
          url: String,
          connections: Array
        },
        { timestamps: true }
      );

    schema.method("toJSON", function() {
      const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
      object.id = _id;
      return object;
    });
  
    const Repository = mongoose.model("repository", schema);

    return Repository;
  };
```

The index.js file:

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = {};
db.mongoose = mongoose;
db.url = dbConfig.url;
db.repository = require("./repository.model.js")(mongoose);
module.exports = db;
```

Relevant parts of the server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

//require("./app/models/repository.model");
const app = express();
const db = require("./app/models");
db.mongoose.connect(db.url, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true
}).then(() => {console.log("Connected to the datbase!");
}).catch(err => {console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
});


var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());
// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." });
});

//const repository = require("./app/routes/repository.routes");
//const repository = require(routes);
//app.use('/',repository);

require("./app/routes/repository.routes")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: You can query the collection using the `find` method.

Comment: @prasad_ hi, I've tried this but I get 0 results (for findall). For find by ID, I get: "Not found Repository with id"